Adding icon to Button in NetBeans not working
Tried to add a icon png to a button in NetBeans.
btnTagDelete.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/team2/notizapp/resources/löschen.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnTagDelete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnTagDeleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

starting the project the frame wont show up and the run quits.
Running the Project in VSCode works as intended.
The error NetBens gives before stopping the project:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
Tried multiple tutorials.
Changed the java runtime.

Did löschen.png not get brought over to Netbeans?

The file is under the wirtten path and I added the file over the editor in NetBeans so the code is completely generated by it.

Use ImageIO to read image files. You will get an error message if the file is not found.

Hello! Erazor, maybe "src/com/team2/notizapp/resources/löschen.png"...

Please check your file path: Make sure that the image file is actually located at /com/team2/notizapp/resources/löschen.png relative to your project's classpath. It's an absolute path relative to the classpath, not a path relative to the current class.

But if that's the case, why does it work with the identical code in VSCode?
